# Spring validation of Map as request parameter with annotations

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I use `javax.validation.constraints` annotations to validate the request parameters. I need to validate emails so I've created an annotation `@EmailValid`, snippet provided below:

```
@Email(message = "Please provide a valid email address")
@Pattern(regexp = ".+@.+\\..+", message = "Please provide a valid email address")
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
public @interface EmailValid {
    String message() default "Please provide a valid email address";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

But it works only for single String field e.g. :

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendEmail", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseVO> sendEmail(@EmailValid String email) {
        // some code for sending email
    }
```

What I need is to validate Map of emails. I have a map `Map<String, String> users` where key is userId and value is an email. So I have a method like this in my controller:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendEmails", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseVO> sendEmails(Map<String, String> users) {
        // some code for sending email
    }
```

Question is how can I validate map values here using my annotation `@EmailValid` and other `javax.validation.constraints` annotations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement custom validation like below.

**First Change your EmailValid.java file.**

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { EmailValidCheck.class })
@Documented
public @interface EmailValid {
    String message() default "Please provide a valid email address";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**Now Implement This ConstraintValidator like Below.**

```
public class EmailValidCheck extends ABaseController implements
        ConstraintValidator<EmailValid, Map<String,String>> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(EmailValid constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Map<String,String> mapOfEmail,
            ConstraintValidatorContext cvc) {
            //Implement Email Validation Login Here.
    }       
}
```

**Change Your Controller Like Below.**

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendEmails", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseVO> sendEmails(@EmailValid Map<String, String> users) {
        // some code for sending email
    }
```

Comment: thank you, nice approach but how can I send custom message response instead of their constraint violation message? I'm using rest and all error responses should be  the same

Comment: Follow this document: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html   .This global exception handler so using this you can handle MethodArgumentNotValidException.class exception in advice controller. e.g https://gist.github.com/matsev/4519323

Comment: Thanks! Came up with controller advice solution for custom error response. There was one more way which is to pass `BindingResult result` to the controller method as an extra parameter, check `result.hasErrors()` and return your error response.